# Как переопределить datasource_url для Spring в docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, spring-data

Подскажите, пжл, почему "backend" ломится на localhost, если SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/postgres  ?
При запуске сервиса "backend" он падает с ошибкой.
[image: скриншот IDEA]

application.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
jwt:
  expiration: 600000
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:latest as build
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:resolve
COPY ./src src/
RUN mvn package

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
EXPOSE 5050
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src/app/target/*.jar app.jar
CMD java -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: у вас в `application.yaml` написано: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres`

Comment: Так в `docker-compose` переопределяться должно, по моему, `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/postgres`